Adding 2 signers for TS Test for Anchor project
I am trying to create a simple swap contract.
The part of the swap function is like this:
    // Transfer tokens from user to pool
        let cpi_accounts_in = token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.user_token_in.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.pool_token_in.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(), // User must authorize this transfer
        };
        let cpi_ctx_in = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            cpi_accounts_in,
        );
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx_in, amount_in)?;
    
        // Transfer tokens from pool to user
        let cpi_accounts_out = token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.pool_token_out.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.user_token_out.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.pool.to_account_info(), // Pool must be the authority for this transfer
        };
        let cpi_ctx_out = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            cpi_accounts_out,
        );
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx_out, output_amount)?;

As you can see, there are 2 different authorities.
However, in the TS test code I have somehting like this:
    const tx = await program.methods
          .swap(new anchor.BN(swapAmountIn), new anchor.BN(minAmountOut))
          .accounts({
            pool: pool.publicKey,
            userTokenIn: userTokenAccountA,
            userTokenOut: userTokenAccountB,
            poolTokenIn: poolTokenAccountA,
            poolTokenOut: poolTokenAccountB,
            user: payer.publicKey,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          })
          .signers([payer])
          .rpc();

Since in this code, I am providing only 1 signer, I am getting this error during anchor test:
    Simulation failed.
    Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account.
    Logs:
    [
      "Program E7nE9N9yiLHhMZDdD9U7duT8SKuiUVLhkE7WJkSwSpkt invoke [1]",
      "Program log: Instruction: Swap",
      "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
      "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
      "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 188115 compute units",
      "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
      "7hGVDEXUfomYMppU7ibSzEvTwgFMg9SWBfrGaWJSY5dL's signer privilege escalated",
      "Program E7nE9N9yiLHhMZDdD9U7duT8SKuiUVLhkE7WJkSwSpkt consumed 18859 of 200000 compute units",
      "Program E7nE9N9yiLHhMZDdD9U7duT8SKuiUVLhkE7WJkSwSpkt failed: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"
    ].

Is there any way I can provide both the signers (user and pool) in the test code?
Or maybe there is a better and neat solution that I am missing?
Thanks!

Make sure that the pool is marked as a singer in your [derive(Accounts)] struct
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyAccounts<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub pool: Signer<'info>,
}

Pass the pool keypair on the client side as part of the signers array
.signers([payer, pool])


Thanks a lot. I spent 1 whole evening searching for this answer
